# Add div after a element and end the div after the content

Tags: jquery, html

I have a h2 a ul and a paragraph. I want to add a div after the h2 that works but I want the ul and the paragraph in that div.
Now it looks like this:

```
<h2>test</h2>
  <div id="test"></div>
<p>test</p>
<ul>
  <li>testlijst</li>
</ul>
```

and it has to be like this:

```
<h2>test</h2>
  <div id="test">
<p>test</p>
<ul>
  <li>testlijst</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I used:

```
$('h2').after('<div id="test"></div>');
```

The div has to be placed after the h2 and end after the content or at the beginning of the next h2 because the content can be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .wrapAll() for all the next siblings of `h2`

```js
$('#faq h2').each(function() {
  $(this).nextUntil('h2').wrapAll('<div id="test"></div>');
})
```

```css
#test {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="faq">
  <h2>test</h2>
  <p>test</p>
  <ul>
    <li>testlijst</li>
  </ul>
  <h2>test</h2>
  <p>test</p>
  <ul>
    <li>testlijst</li>
  </ul>
  <h2>test</h2>
  <p>test</p>
  <ul>
    <li>testlijst</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<h2>test2</h2>
<p>test</p>
<ul>
  <li>testlijst</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm sorry i forgot to say this but: The div has to be placed after the h2 and end after the content or at the beginning of the next h2 because the content can be different.

Comment: This works but i use the h2 mulitple times and now it wraps all the othe h2's in thet one h2

Comment: This works thanks alot now one more thing this only has the happen in a div #faq im sorry i forgot to say all these things ;/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var div = $('<div id="test"></div>');
div.append($('p')).append($('ul'));
$('h2').after(div);
```

Comment: please fix your accents. (')

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery wrapAll function.

```
$("p").next().andSelf().wrapAll('<div id="test" />');
```

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uba87of5/

Answer (score 0):

The div will be placed after the h2 and end after the content or at the beginning of the next h2

```
$('h2').nextUntil('h2').wrapAll('<div id="test"></div>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ew9hzfu2/2/

Answer (score 0):

seems to be, what you want to do is this: `$('#test').append($('p,ul'))`
[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/r1ndv3qe/)

this will move
`<p>test</p> and <ul><li>testlijst</li></ul>`
into
`<div id="test"></div>`